# Getting smallest numerical values in master list and then how frequent it appears

Tags: python-3.x, knn

Yesterday, I asked how to calculate euclidean for 3d coordinates and I figured it out:

```
import math
from math import sqrt

# returns array of euclidian distances
def calc_distance(point, points): 
    ret_dists = []
    for dest_point in points:
        dist = sum([pow(x1-x2, 2) for x1, x2 in zip(point, dest_point)])
        ret_dists.append(round(pow(dist, 0.5), 3))
    return ret_dists

dA = []; dB = []; dC = [];

distclassA = calc_distance([1,0,1],[[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[1,2,1],[1,2,0]])
distclassB = calc_distance([1,0,1],[[1,2,2],[2,2,2],[1,2,-1],[2,2,3]])
distclassC = calc_distance([1,0,1],[[-1,-1,-1],[0,-1,-2],[0,-1,1],[-1,-2,1]])

dA.append(distclassA)
dB.append(distclassB)
dC.append(distclassC)

master = dA + dB + dC
print(master)
```

This gives you:

```
[[1.732, 1.414, 2.0, 2.236], [2.236, 2.449, 2.828, 3.0], [3.0, 3.317, 1.414, 2.828]]
```

For my prompt, what this answer means is that for my test data point, I want to label it as either in groupA, groupB, or groupC. The euclidean distances calculated pertain to each group, so there are 4 (x,y,z) coordinates in each group, and there are 3 groups. 
So here comes the problem, I've been thinking for awhile on how to write a script that will just tell me which group my test point (1,0,1) belongs in based on how close it is to each group. As I increase the amount of points neighbors (this is a KNN problem) from K=1 to K=3 or K=4, it is obvious that the test point belongs in groupA, since the distances are the smallest.

As you can see, I stored each euclidean distances set into separate lists dA, dB, and dC. Then I combined them into a master list, master. I thought this could be a way but I feel like it's easier but longer to just write loops to go through each list dA, dB, and dC to find the 1 closest point, then 2 closest points, then 3 and so on. This way I could then have if statements so that if there are more "shorter" distance points in a list, then it would belong there.

But I'm not 100% sure, so how should I go about doing this? Any sample code would be greatly appreciated! Thank you again!